# Unable to login to SqlServer running in container started via Docker-compose on Ubuntu VM on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

If I build and run container with just Dockerfile (without docker-compose)

```
sudo docker-compose up --build -d
```

and then run it with :

```
sudo docker run  --hostname sqlserver -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear" -p 1433:1433 -d sql
```

I am able to

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 1StrongPwdclear
```

But, when I build and run the container with docker-compose:

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

I get :

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed
>   for user 'sa'..

I don't understand why. I mean I am practically using the same Dockerfile in both the cases.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS build
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak .
COPY restore-backup.sql .


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS release

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
    coreapi:
        build:
            context: ./theapi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    sqlserver:
        build:
            context: ./sqlserver
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"    
        environment: 
            - ACCEPT_EULA="Y"
            - SA_PASSWORD="1StrongPwdclear"
    angular:
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "4300:4200"
```

I have also check if container is running fine:

[image]

This leads me to believe that there is something wrong with my docker-compose file. I am not sure what.

EDIT:

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    coreapi:
        build:
            context: ./theapi
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "5000:5000"
    sqlserver:
        build:
            context: ./sqlserver
        ports:
            - "1433:1433"    
        environment: 
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear
    angular:
        build:
            context: ./frontend
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "4300:4200"
```

Folder structure on ubuntu vm:

[image]

```
frontend-- Dockerfile:

FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY ./package.json .

EXPOSE 4200

RUN npm i

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

**sqlserver- Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS build
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear

WORKDIR /tmp
COPY AdventureWorksLT2017.bak .
COPY restore-backup.sql .


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS release

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
```

theapi-- dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2
EXPOSE 80/tcp

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "theapi.dll", "--urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

Comment: Do you the login attempt anything if you run (inside the container) `cat /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog` (note you may need to use `sudo` if you don't run this as `root`).

Comment: @Larnu Lots and lots of ` Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 8.
2020-04-02 15:50:11.61 Logon       Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 138.91.125.91]`

Comment: I don't understand how is that possible. Password is exactly the same as in dockerfile.

Comment: I would guess that it is not. Obviously you haven't posted your real `sa` password, nor should you, but the error is pretty clear here.

Comment: @Larnu It is he real password. It's ok because I have set up the vm only for a couple of hours to practice.

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, you just need to change the environment setting like this:

```
    environment: 
        - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
        - SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear
```

Then it will work fine. You can take a look at the [environment](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) in docker-compose.

**Update:**

I do not have other things you used, so I just can test the docker-compose for sqlserver. The Dockerfile here:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS build
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest AS release

ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
```

And the docker-compose file here:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  sqlserver-1:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
      - SA_PASSWORD=1StrongPwdclear
```

Then I can also connect to the sqlserver just with the command:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P 1StrongPwdclear
```

Comment: still same issue

Comment: @SamuraiJack It's wired. I reproduce the same issue as you and it solved it with my answer. Can you share all the things? I can take a test for you.

Comment: @SamuraiJack See my update, I do not have the things that you copy into the image, but I think it does not affect the result.

Comment: I will remove the VM and start over and see if that helps

Comment: @SamuraiJack What about the problem now? Do you solve it?

Comment: @SamuraiJack Any response? I didn't see any updates. Do you work on this issue?

Comment: I am currently not working on that. But rest assured I will be trying that out over the weekends and let you know.

Comment: I think there was an issue with the VM. Thanks.